# Passing variable from 1st page to 3rd page in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I need to pass a variable from page one to third page how do I make it?

- I can pass variable from 1 page to next
- how can i to pass variable from 1st to second page and same value to 3rd page

here is the example

```
<a href="page2.php?myname=Suraj Mittal&age=22&fav_color=White&fav_fruit=Grapes">Click here to send variables in the URL</a>
```

second page

```
<?php
 $name = $_GET['myname'];
$age = $_GET['age'];
$color = $_GET['fav_color'];
$fruit = $_GET['fav_fruit'];
        echo "My name is ".$name.". and I am ".$age." years old. My favourite color is ".$color." and my favourite fruit is ".$fruit.".";
?>
```

Comment: save the values in $_SESSION and fetch them in any page

Comment: There are multiple ways to reach your goal. 1. Sessions 2. Pass through the URL 3. Post 4. Cookie 5. Globals. What do you exactly want?

Comment: @Wehelie but i need pass variable to many pages

Comment: You can use session variables on any page

Comment: @GuyT which is safe and best to pass variable to 2page continues

Comment: @sanoj lawrence, if you read it carefully, it will make sense my friend, I promise.

Comment: @sanojlawrence No method is safe by themselves. You have to validate the user input. I would advice you to use `$_SESSION` in a case like this.

Comment: @GuyT but how to do that passing value to three pages

Comment: @sanojlawrence Like the others already mentioned: start with `session_start();` on every page and use `$_SESSION['name'] = $value` to set the session variable and `echo $_SESSION['name']` to use the value.

Comment: [Saroj](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3836908/sanoj-lawrence) I think you should use either session or POST method in this type of case. Pass through URL is not a safe way and cookie may cause problem if user destroy in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use session to do this

```
 session_start();

 $_SESSION["myname"] = $_GET['myname'] ;

 $_SESSION["age"] = $_GET['age'] ;
```

and then you can access this `SESSION variables` on any page.

on your page where u want to access age, do like this

```
$age=$_SESSION["age"] ;
```

Comment: <a href="#">Ahmedabad</a> how to add session here the value here is Ahmedabad

Comment: you want to add "Ahmedabad" in Session or you want to display "Ahmedabad" using session ?

Comment: @saroj what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: @SunilChhimpa <a href="#">Ahmedabad</a> its a link to a page and Ahmedabad is value to make session with that

Comment: you can do it like this <a href="#">echo $age;</a> or you can echo session value directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the variables again using the same method, passing them through the URL or put them in a session so they can be accessed anywhere, at least while the session is still active.

For example:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['myname'] = $_GET['myname'];
$_SESSION['age'] = $_GET['age'];
$_SESSION['fav_color'] = $_GET['fav_color'];
$_SESSION['fav_fruit'] = $_GET['fav_fruit'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variables. Bascially, PHP session variables could be accessed anywhere inside the application.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["myname"]    = $_GET['myname'];
$_SESSION["age"]       = $_GET['age'];
$_SESSION["fav_color"] = $_GET['fav_color'];
$_SESSION["fav_fruit"] = $_GET['fav_fruit'];
```

To Get the entire session variables/values in your third page:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: but in 1st page there are many variable and user has to select a variable and it has to move to 3 pages how to do that with session

Comment: You could store as many variables in the $_SESSION variable and use it in any page.

Comment: This might help http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: You can find useful information at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: NEVER EVER USE w3schools! It's not an official resource!

Comment: anybody let me know why the downvote?

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes I would say SESSION is the best bet here!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

On first page you used this URL:

```
<a href="page2.php?var_one=1&var_two=2&var_three=3">Go to second page</a>
```

Similarly on second page you can use below URL:

```
<a href="page3.php?var_one=1&var_two=2&var_three=3">Go to third page</a>
```

Let me know if it worked out for you. If details needed knock me.

Regards.